# Find the value of the integral on the contour C

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration

Ok, so I'm trying to figure out this problem. It asks to find the value of the contour integral $\dfrac{e^z}{z^2(z-\pi i)}$ on the contour $C$ shown in the following figure

[image]

I believe that in order to solve this I have to use the formula $\int f(z)=dz=\int fz(t)z'(t) dt$ There are not points in the figure, it is continuous, so I am not sure what to do about the integration limits, leave them a and b???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Break the curve $C$ up into three pieces $C_1$, $C_2$, and $C_3$, where each $C_1$ is the top loop traversed CCW, $C_2$ is the middle loop traversed CCW, and $C_3$ is the right loop traversed CCW.

Then, $\displaystyle\oint_C \dfrac{e^z}{z^2(z-\pi i)}\,dz = -\oint_{C_1} \dfrac{e^z}{z^2(z-\pi i)}\,dz + \oint_{C_2} \dfrac{e^z}{z^2(z-\pi i)}\,dz - \oint_{C_3} \dfrac{e^z}{z^2(z-\pi i)}\,dz$.

The function $\dfrac{e^z}{z^2(z-\pi i)}$ has a double pole at $z = 0$ and a single pole at $z = \pi i$. So, the interior of $C_1$ has only one pole at $z = \pi i$, the interior of $C_2$ has a double pole at $z = 0$, and the interior of $C_3$ has no poles.

Now, apply the residue theorem to calculate the integrals over $C_1$, $C_2$, and $C_3$.

---

To calculate the integrals, first use partial fractions to get $\dfrac{1}{z^2(z-\pi i)} = \dfrac{1/\pi^2}{z} + \dfrac{i/\pi}{z^2} - \dfrac{1/\pi^2}{z-\pi i}$.

Therefore, $\displaystyle\oint_{C_i}\dfrac{e^z}{z^2(z-\pi i)}\,dz = \dfrac{1}{\pi^2}\oint_{C_i}\dfrac{e^z}{z}\,dz + \dfrac{i}{\pi}\oint_{C_i}\dfrac{e^z}{z^2}\,dz - \dfrac{1}{\pi^2}\oint_{C_i}\dfrac{e^z}{z-\pi i}\,dz$.

Applying Cauchy's Integral formula, you have that $\displaystyle\oint_{C_i}\dfrac{f(z)}{(z-a)^{n+1}}\,dz = \dfrac{2\pi i f(a)}{n!}$ if $a$ lies in the interior of the curve $C_i$, and $0$ otherwise. Can you finish the problem from here?

Comment: When you say poles, I assume that you mean zeroes? Ive never heard them referred as poles.

Comment: See, my problem is how to actually apply the Cauchy Integral theorem. Every example that I look up skips a lot of steps, but I would say that the answer for this is $-2\pi i$

Comment: I just added a few more hints. Let me know if you still have any questions.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Im walking into work right now, i will take a look at this on my break and let you know if I have any other questions. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @JimmyK4542Sooo, going from where you left off, I took Cauchy's Integral Formula formula and applied it to $C_1$, $C_2$, $C_3$. Assuming that i plugged into it correctly, I got 1 as my answer. Not sure if this is correct